# When is grounding required, and will it blow my circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, grounding

I have designed and tested (via breadboard) a PIC chip based circuit for controlling an LED light strip.

It's got a very simple control system, that uses standard light switches so it can look fairly normal in a room.

The circuit uses a barrel jack for power and is connected to a 5V 10A power brick, which plugs into the wall.

My concern is that I know some light switch back plates, particularly metal ones, take a ground wire.

1. If I use a plastic back plate do I need to a use ground wire?
2. My circuit has very wide traces (283mils) to handle sending 10 amperes to the LED strip, and then I used pours on both sides of the board, (5V one side, ground on the other side) to give as much extra as possible.
   If I connect the back plate to ground through my circuit, is some condition where too much current will pass through the circuit?

Comment: Your approach, using 5V to power a 50W light strip, isn't very good. The IR drops you will encounter with actual wiring will be a big problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of back plate (assume it is  metal)?

Comment: @hacktastical can you elaborate?
The light strip is rated at 5V and depending on the color configuration it has a max draw of 9.6 amperes. I had some problems initially getting it to respond correctly - it would display random colors on random lights - which was solved by putting a 1000µF capacitor across it's +5 and GND lines. I believe happens because the power supply cannot respond fast enough without the capacitor.

Comment: @Jay The back panel is just the box that houses the electricals of the switch.
Some are metal, some are plastic.

Comment: @MercilessMaverick if the metal is isolated, and there is no chance any part of electric/electronics leak current outside the box, why bother, any good reason?

Comment: if your switch enclosure does not have high voltage, why your concerning about ground? if by "ground" you mean Protective Earth, it is all about high voltage only

Comment: @Jay - That's what I'm trying to find out. Watching Youtube I've seen that some have this ground wire connected to the back plate Live, Neutral, connect to the switch and ground connected to the back. So I'm trying to find out if I need to redesign my circuit to handle for this type of situation which isn't at all obvious to me why it exists. 
I anticipate that so long as its plastic it should be fine

Comment: @user263983 amazing. Thanks. It was probably key information that I don't usually deal with high voltage electronics, so its never been a key concern for me, but I'm making something that uses components (switch casing) that are used in high voltage systems

Comment: if you have in same enclosure high voltage and low, it should be separated.

Comment: casing is not important, voltage is.

Comment: Understood. My entire circuit doesn't do anything over 5V so there's no problem there

Comment: #14 ga wire as typically used for lighting has a resistance of about 0.025 ohms per foot. A 15 foot run from would be 0.32 ohms. 10A over that run would result in a 330 mV IR drop in each direction, 600mV total. So your strip would only be getting 4.4V, and probably malfunction as a result. You can increase the wire size, but it would be better to use a higher supply voltage and lower current.

Comment: @MercilessMaverick , That was a rhetorical question. There are religious codes for road vehicles, but that is not for everything.

Comment: @hacktastical AWG#10 usually used for low voltage

Comment: @user263983 yes, they can, and they also use 12 to 24V, not 5V. It would make more sense if the controller / LED power were mounted close to the LEDs and fed with a higher voltage, which is more typical for structure wiring.

Comment: @hacktastical, agreed, 5V is not usual choiсe and should be used only if power source close to load

Comment: Ok, @hacktastical I understand. The control box will be close to the strip (inches away). 
The strip itself is 2 meters. Its actually in the data sheet that if you want to run more than 2m you need a separate power line. I've seen some things about providing power every so many feet but it should be Ok in this case but I know what to do if there are issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up with different things, protective earth as "ground" required for protection against electrical shock in high voltage system. in low voltage ground is used for protecting system from EMI. do not use for that ground from receptacle.separate grounding system is used in labs, etc. in your case the system will work without ground. just twist the wires together.

Answer (score 0):

The current-carrying parts of a domestic light switch must not be grounded - there should be no connection between those parts and the mounting bracket.

Comment: Could you explain why, please? Is that the "code"?

Comment: The current-carrying parts of a light switch will normally be carrying 120 V - connecting them to thte Safety Ground (green wire) will cause a short circuit.

Comment: The OP's question is not about 120V. I was wondering if there are law binding codes.

Comment: In any application, the current-carrying parts (the switch contacts) must not normally be connected to Ground - this is, to me, a common-sense requirement - no "code" required.